# Using commands in a text file

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am looking to use a text file to make a really basic way of controlling a robot 
To do this I would like the have a txt file like below

```
move #1 P1453 #5 p983 T2000
wait 2000
```

If I could read each line and use the first word to decide what to do with the data following it. I would need to be able to `serial.wrightline` the Text following the word move and use the word wait to pause the program in milliseconds. I have found how to read each line of a file but am unaware of how to
separate the word's at the start of the line so i can just use the data following

Comment: look at split, indexof & substring!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand this part:

> I have found how to read each line of a file but am unaware of how to
>   separate the word's at the start of the line

This is how I do this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file1.txt");

while ( !sr.EndOfStream )
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
    string command = parts[0].Trim();

    //Use parts[x] where x > 0 to extract other items of the line
}
```